# How to prove a triangle similarity problem

Tags: geometry, triangles

If I have a triangle $ABC$ with point $E$ lying on $BC$ and point $D$ lying on $AB$ where $AE$ is the height to $BC$ and $CD$ is the height to $AB$, how can I prove that triangle $ABC$ is similar to triangle $BED$?[image]

Comment: May you add a graph?

Comment: ok, I just did.

Comment: Can you draw a circle with the points A, D, E, C? I found this advice on smoop.com "The easiest way to figure out which quadrilaterals are cyclic is to simply draw the smallest possible circle around them"

Comment: I found a simple way to verify that ADEC is a cyclic quadrilateral. I just measured with a protractor two different opposite angles and I added the results. It gives 180 degrees. That shows that is a cyclic quadrilateral.

Comment: Really your graph does not show exactly 180 degrees, but that is because your right angles do not have 90 degrees.

Answer (score 1):

Since $CD \perp AB$ and $AE \perp BC$, we have that $ADEC$ to be a cyclic quadrilateral. This means $\angle{DCE} = \angle{DAE}$ and $\angle{DCA} = \angle{DEA}$. This means
$$\angle{C} = \angle{DCE} + \angle{DCA} = \underbrace{\angle{DAE} + \angle{DEA} = \angle{EDB}}_{\text{Exterior angle of }\Delta ADE}$$
By a similar argument, $\angle{A} = \angle{BED}$.

Further $\angle{B}$ is common to $\Delta ABC$ and $\Delta EBD$.

Hence, the two triangles are similar.

Comment: May you give the complete explanation for angle A = angle BED? Thanks!

Comment: Why we can conclude that angle DCA = angle DEA? Thanks!

Comment: @Beginner $\angle{DCE} = \angle{DAE}$ and $\angle{DCA} = \angle{DEA}$ (because angles in the same segment). Also, $\angle{A} = \angle{BED}$ by the same argument for $\angle{C} = \angle{EDB}$.

Comment: I'm having problems figuring that out as well. Could you please explain what means for an angle to be in the same segment? Could you also provide an alternative proof for angle DCA = angle DEA?

Comment: Also why is ADEC a cyclic quadriliteral?

Comment: @usser17762 I was thinking that angle A is not necessary to check because if two angles of the triangles are equal, the other one, automatically is equal too. Thanks for your explantions!